# How to create same token for same input in Java

Tags: java, string

I am a beginner in java, I need to generate a token which should be same for the same input, otherwise it should be different.

Comment: Or even the string's `hashCode()`

Comment: Do you want a simple hashing or you look for an encryption mechanism?

Comment: hashing, just give examples

Comment: your question is not clear what do u want? do u want hashing or encryption machanism for ur string? for hashing use hashCode() and for encryption use md5 of Strings

Comment: @YousufUmar: nonsense. The hashCode() doesn't provide any guarantee of uniqueness. And MD5 is not encryption. It's a cryptographoc hashing algorithm. And there are better algorithms than MD5 (which should be considered as obsolete). A cryptographic hash doesn't guarantee uniqueness either, but you would have to be extremely unlucky to have same hashes with different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get integer hash code by String.hashCode() but my suggestion is better to use SHA Hashing algorithm(MD5 is outdated) ( read [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) for more about hashing). Following code snippets may help you to get hash string which is unique.

```
Strign text="text input"
java.security.MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
String uniqueValue=bin2hex(hash); //To Convert binary to hexadecimal string 


static String bin2hex(byte[] data) {
  return String.format("%0" + (data.length * 2) + 'x', new BigInteger(1, data));
}
```